# Inverse of the central difference operator

Tags: computational-statistics, numerics

The [central difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences) is a method to approximate numerically the derivative of a function sampled at discrete intervals. In R, one would do:

```
n<-100
y<-cumsum(rnorm(n))
y_p[1]<-diff(y[1:2])
for(i in 2:(n-1)) y_p[i]<-diff(y[c(i-1,i+1)])/2
y_p[n]<-diff(y[c(n-1,n)])
```

My question is, what is the comonly accepted inverse to this operator? (preferably in pseudo code form to avoid ambuiguity)

Best,

Comment: I don't think there is a reason for migrate, but this would be also on topic on [Computational Science SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think away from the edges you might want to divide the difference by 2.

Comment: @Henry: indeed, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a constant difference (equal to `y[1]`) you can reconstruct this with

```
z <- rep(NA,n)
z[1] <- 0 
z[2] <- z[1] + y_p[1]
for (i in 2:(n-1)) { z[i+1] <- z[i-1] + 2*y_p[i] }
```

though you might prefer `for (i in 3:length(y_p)) { z[i] <- z[i-2] + 2*y_p[i-1] }` as the last line.

You can see the constant difference with

```
plot(y-z)
```